# Extract column data on the basis of another column levels in r

Tags: r, reshape, dcast

My data looks like below: Column 1 is binary variable and column 2 is continuous variable.

```
Col1    Col2
0       21
0       34
1       36
0       24
1       96
.       .
.       .
0       25
```

And so on. I want my output in new data frame where column 1 levels as two
   new different columns("0" and "1") and corresponding column 2 values below 
   both. Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(77)
Col1 <- sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = TRUE)
Col2 <- round(rnorm(50),2)
dat <- data.frame(Col1, Col2)
```

So, basically my output should look like:

```
   "0"    "1"
   21     36
   34     96              
   24     .              
    .     .
    .     .
   25
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually asking for here. Please provide a reproducible example, as well as what you would like the output to look like.

Comment: I provided you a reproducible example, but I'm still not sure what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hi  - I have added my output above. Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter if the `length()` of the 0s and 1st are not equal?

Comment: yes, length will not be equal.

Comment: actually, my objective is to perform two sample t-test. This is the reason i want my output in the above format.

Comment: OK, this is not the proper format for the two-sample t-test. By putting numbers on the same row, you are telling R that they belong to the same person - which is not the case for that statistical test.

Comment: I'll answer below how to run the t.test on this data.

Comment: column 1 is my binary variable(0-No Rain, 1- Rain) and column 2(no. of units sold) is continuous variable. Basically, i want to find correlation between two variables. I thought two sample t test would be great to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conducting a t.test in R.  It is best practice to convert your factor variable (the 0/1) to a factor before running the t.test. The function assumes each row is a separate person, and they belong to the group specified in Col1.

```
Col1 <- sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = TRUE)
Col2 <- round(rnorm(50),2)
dat <- data.frame(Col1, Col2)

dat$Col1 <- factor(dat$Col1) 
t.test(Col2 ~ Col1, data = dat)
```

Comment: Thanks @Twitch_City for your guidance. Column 1 is my binary variable(0-No Rain, 1- Rain) and Column 2(no. of units sold) is continuous variable. Basically, i want to find correlation between two variables. Do you suggest two sample t test will be useful?

Comment: You are confusing statistical tests - at their basic level, correlation is to find an association between two variables, the t-test is to look for differences. So if your hypothesis is: does the amount of spending vary based on whether there is rain or not? Then the t-test is appropriate.  You can run this as a correlation, but the phrasing would be a bit different - as the amount of rain increases, does spending also increase? But since one of the variables is binary, this is called the "point biserial correlation".

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I should have mentioned my hypothesis in the beginning. My bad. Thanks once again for guiding me!

Answer (score 1):

```
  df <- data.frame(C1 = c("1","0","0","1","1"), C2 = c(11,21,22,31,35))
  df
  #   C1 C2
  # 1  1 11
  # 2  0 21
  # 3  0 22
  # 4  1 31
  # 5  1 35

 One <- df[df$C1 == "1","C2"]
 Zero <- df[df$C1 == "0","C2"]
 One
 # [1] 11 31 35
 Zero
 # [1] 21 22

 n <- max(length(One),length(Zero))
 n
 # 3

 length(One) <- 3
 length(Zero) <- 3

 Result <- cbind(One,Zero)
 Result
 #      One Zero
 # [1,]  11   21
 # [2,]  31   22
 # [3,]  35   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dat <- data.frame("0" = data$Col2[data$Col1 == 0],
                  "1" = data$Col2[data$Col1 == 1])
head(dat)
```